# How can I load a div when I click on a li?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I load a `<div>` when I click on a `<li>`?

```
<ul id="courseNav">
    <li class="title"><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
    <hr style="margin-top: -0.8px">                
    <li class="topics" style="margin-top: -12px"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
    <li class="topics"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
    <li class="topics"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I click on a `<li>` in my `<ul>` I want a `<div>` to be loaded on my website. The `<div>` is in another HTML file.

Example Div:

```
<div id="topicDiv">
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0 col-md-8 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-0">
                        <h6 class="courseOptions">Topic Title</h6>
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" style="width: 380px min-width: 20px" class="form-control" name="text" id="editorText">
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: how do you want to load that div and where do u want to load it?

Comment: I want to know how I can load it. I want to load it in a section of my website.

Comment: @DeniedAnull why don't you just put the div in the same HTML page and hide it until the li is clicked?

Comment: Because I want the div to be different for every <li> in my <ul>.

Comment: can you post an example of the other div ? Are you the administrator of the other website?

Comment: Just provide the link to the page where the div is and I may be able to write a custom YQL query for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you want to load the div with the new html within your `li` tag, you can follow this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qaoturwz/

I have just added a basic div with some text in it, you can get your html from Ajax and load that into your li or elsewhere in the page.

Comment: How can I get my html from AJAX?

Comment: you can create a div element and then use the load event of jquery to load an external file like $('#divHtml').load('test.html') but as @Pedro suggested, you need to have CORS enabled

Answer (score 0):

A working example of what you need using [YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql)(just in case the site hasn't [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)),jQuery and ajax .

```
<ul id="courseNav">
<li class="title"><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
<hr style="margin-top: -0.8px">                
<li class="topics" style="margin-top: -12px"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
<li class="topics"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
<li class="topics"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="output"> </div>


<script>

$("li").click(function(){
             url = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%22%20and%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fdiv%2Fh3%2Fa'&format=json"

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function(){},
                error: function(e){},
                complete: function(){},
                success: function( data ) {

                        var post = data.query.results.a || [];
                        if(post[0]){
                        $("#output").html("");
                        $("#output").append(post[0].content + " " + post[0].href);
                     }       
                  }
             });
        });
<script>
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3sh7kdgc/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can load it with ajax from javascript/jquery.

- Capture the click event on your lis: http://api.jquery.com/click/
- Load the file via http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
- Add the data to your page: http://api.jquery.com/html/ or http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: @DeniedAnull what part do you have problems with?

Comment: The last part (Add the data to page). @Andy